# Django: Need to check for QuerySet existence before looping through it

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have observed in several Django projects the following common pattern:

```
queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(...)
if queryset:
    for obj in queryset:
        do_something()
```

I realize that by checking **queryset** Django is already populating its cache so we don't hit the DB again when executing the **for** loop.

According to the documentation, the queryset is also evaluated when looping through it.

So my question is:

```
Is there any benefit in including the queryset check before the loop?
```

I am also aware of [exists()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists), but let's consider for this particular case I am not going to use it.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need to check?

```
if queryset:
    for obj in queryset:
        do_something()
```

and

```
for obj in queryset:
    do_something()
```

are essentially the same. If the queryset is empty, the loop will never be executed. Otherwise, it will.

`queryset.exists()` is not a good idea as it causes an extry db hit, when you would pull the data anyway.

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking. I asked that because I have seen it in several projects. Thanks again.